# Swiper Grid View- Is there any way to change the order of the slides

Tags: angular, swiper.js, ionic7

```
<swiper-container class="mySwiper"  slides-per-view="3" grid-rows="2" grid-fill="row" [navigation]="false"
    space-between="30">
    <swiper-slide *ngFor="let item of lists;">
      <div>
        {{item.name}}
      </div>
    </swiper-slide>
 </swiper-container>
```

If there are 13 slides then it will display the slides in this order by default:

[image]

I want the order to be:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching how to achieve the same behavior. I don't believe this is supported but the only workaround I've found so far is described here:

https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3193

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35768402)